# HoughLinesP parameters! unit?

Tags: c#, opencv

I am using OpenCV 2.4.2

and here is a quotation from OpenCV documentation

> C++: void HoughLinesP(InputArray image, OutputArray lines, double rho, double theta, int threshold, double minLineLength=0, double maxLineGap=0 )
>
> Parameters:
>
> **image** – 8-bit, single-channel binary source image. The image may be modified by the function.
>
> **lines** – Output vector of lines. Each line is represented by a
> 4-element vector   , where   and   are the ending points of each
> detected line segment.
>
> **rho** – Distance resolution of the accumulator in pixels.
>
> **theta** – Angle resolution of the accumulator in radians.
>
> **threshold** – Accumulator threshold parameter. Only those lines are
> returned that get enough votes().
>
> **minLineLength** – Minimum line length. Line segments shorter than that
> are rejected.
>
> **maxLineGap** – Maximum allowed gap between points on the same line to
> link them

My Question is

are **minLineLength** and **maxLineGap** measured in Pixels? or what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Digging into an old Intel OpenCV manual, you can see that it describes LineLength as Pixels
http://opencv.jp/opencv-1.0.0_org/docs/opencvman_old.pdf

> It retrieves no more than linesNumber line segments; each of those must
>   be not shorter than lineLength pixels.

Pixels seem to be the most logical here.  Rho, the distance resolution of the accumulator is defined as being in Pixels.

The sample here shows a value of 30 being used:
http://www.scribd.com/doc/77374092/155/cv-HoughLinesP